# Box Java SDK - Unable to download/delete specific versions of a file

Tags: java, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am using the latest [Box SDK](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2) for interacting with the Box API.
I am able to successfully upload, download, delete and upload new version of a file.

However, I am unable to to delete one file version out of many, as suggested on the SDK page :

```
BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObj = new BoxDefaultRequestObject();
requestObject.getRequestExtras.setIfMatch(etag); //etag is file version starting from 0
boxClient.getFilesManager().deleteFile(fileId, requestObj);
```

This fails to delete the version and instead deletes the entire file.

Similarly, I am unable to download a specific file version either.
Code for download :

```
BoxDefaultRequestObject downloadReq = new BoxDefaultRequestObject();
downloadReq.getRequestExtras().setIfMatch(versionId);
InputStream is = boxClient.getFilesManager().downloadFile(fileId, downloadReq);
```

This downloads the latest version only.
Can anyone suggest how to make it work?

Comment: I was able to make download of a specific version work as follows : `requestObj.getRequestExtras().addQueryParam("version", boxVersion);`
Here, 
`boxVersion` is the id of the BoxFileVersion object that I get from the list of versions by calling 
`boxClient.getFilesManager().getFileVersions(fileId, null);`

Still, need help on deleting a specific version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching the source code of the open-source SDK, I realized that the capability didn't existed. I have made the necessary changes and submitted the pull request with them [here](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/pull/220)

Code to delete version :

`boxClient.getFilesManager().deleteFileVersion(fileId, boxVersion, requestObj);`

Marking this as as answer as it is resolved.